# swift sourceApplication not working when app is running

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

AppDelegate

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {        
        return true
    }
```

info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>Icon-App-60x60</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>net.mycomp.myapp.pdf</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>PDF data type</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>PDF dosyalarını çevir</string>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.text</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>net.mycomp.myapp.pdf</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <string>pdf</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

I want open pdf file with my apps. When my app is close app not crash but when app is running app crash.

Also, if i delete sourceApplication app is not crash

Comment: That delegate method has been deprecated since iOS 9.0.

Answer (score 1):

This is a deprecated method try this

```
 func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL,
                 options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool

{
}
```